# Serial communication between Computer & Arduino via XBee

Tags: serial, wireless, uart, xbee

I configured two XBees using [XCTU](http://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions/xctu-software/xctu), connected them to the computer and sent Bytes back and forth. ***Works.***

[image: Works.]

This is the current, non-working setup:

- 1 XBee, connected to the Computer using a [SparkFun XBee Explorer USB](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11812).
- 1 XBee, connected to an Arduino Mega using [SparkFun XBee Explorer Regulated](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11373)

  - GND to GND
  - 5V to 5V on the Arduino
  - DOUT to TX1 on the Arduino
  - DIN to RX1 on the Arduino

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  //After 3 seconds the XBee should send out a couple of "A"s coming from the serial port
  delay(3000);
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    Serial1.print("A");
    delay(100);
    i++;
  }
}
void loop() {
  //If anything is sent to the XBee it should appear in the Arduino's serial buffer
  //making the LED on pin 13 turn on
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
}
```

The DOUT LED on the Explorer Regulated flashes as supposed to but nothing is received on the computer where my Terminal application is listening.

Same when I send something from the Terminal, the LED on pin 13 of the Arduino does not indicate any bytes in the buffer, meaning that the XBee probably never received anything.

I already tried swapping TX & RX, resulting in the DIN LED blinking instead of DOUT. Transmission still not working.

Comment: Try swapping TX and RX.

Comment: Is the terminal configured for 9600 baud? Are both xbees configured to it too?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, they're set to 9600 baud. Probably would have noticed already when transmitting data with the Terminal.

Comment: Anyway, `DOUT` is an output of XBee, so it should go to the input of Arduino, which is RX, rather than TX. First fix this. BTW, make sure you don't have any hard/soft flow control

Comment: @Dario Swapping TX and RX was the solution? Please share it with is for when we get the same problem :) `Output of one device is likely to be input of the other and vice versa. It's not that RX connects to RX and TX to TX, they should be cross-connected.`

Comment: @FuaZe I got it to work using a different board as well as connecting RX to RX and TX to TX, what seems a little odd but at least it works. I'll post a detailed answer in a few hours.